# Return multiple values in an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Im not sure if I am wording this correctly or not.

I have a filter set up with acf checkboxes that will display an item selected.  However, the current array i'm submitting only sends/gets one value.  If an result has more than one value it doesn't get returned if any of its values are selected

My current array is as follows:

```
$meta_array = array(
            array(
                'key' => 'color_options',
                'value' => $_GET['color_options']
            )
    );
```

I know it currently one gets one color in the arrow.  How can I set the value to get either 1 color, or multiple colors?

Any tips or references would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to send/get an array ("more than one") with `$_GET` query parameters?

Comment: What are you sending via `$_GET['color_options']`?  What do you do with `$meta_array`?

Comment: Im trying to get all the values, whether its 1 or more with the $_Get parameter.  Not sure if thats the way to go.  This is fairly new to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one checkbox to hold multiple colour options then name all the checkboxes like this :-

```
<input type="checkbox" name="color_options[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="color_options[]" value="2">
etc
```

Then when you get the data back to PHP the $_GET['color_options'] will be an array containing the values of all the checked checkboxes.